# SQLite and Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My problem is that I can't retrieve the data from a database using a Cursor, and in all cases a SQLite Exception will be thrown

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE BOOKS ("
     + "_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
     + "Name TEXT, "
     + "Sub_Field TEXT, "
     + "Cover INTEGER, "
     + "Priority INTEGER);");

ContentValues BookValue = new ContentValues();

BookValue.put("Name", "Cisco");
BookValue.put("Sub_Field", "Net");
BookValue.put("Cover", R.drawable.cappuccino );
BookValue.put("Priority", 1);

db.insert("BOOKS", null, BookValue);
```

MainActivity:

```
try {
  SQLiteOpenHelper myDatabase = new myDatabase(this);
  db = myDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
  myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

  cursor = db.query("BOOK", new String[] {"Name", "Sub_Field"}, null,null,  null, null,null);

  if (cursor != null) {
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String name = cursor.getString(0);
     myText.setText(name);
  }

} catch (SQLiteException e ) {
   myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
   myText.setText("Try Again, you're soon to achieve your Goal...");
   myText.setTextSize(20);
}
```

Comment: Add your exceptiion which are occurring with question plz

Comment: `Slqite Exception error` means that you have some problems with SQLite. For more info you should read the error message and stacktrace.

Comment: what is the error? Try adding a `Log.d("TAG", "exception = " + e.toString());` in `catch(SQLiteException e) {}` to log the error.

Comment: 1. `db.query` will not return `null` .. 2. you does nothing with `cursor.moveToFirst()` result

Comment: just what display is what i write if the code inside the Try not work corectlly

Answer (score 0):

In you query (select) your table name is "BOOK", but you are create table "BOOKS" and insert data into "BOOKS"